# Adding current row to the output

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to find/document the current row in the output of this macro. I cannot take credit for the code below, a gracious person @Variatus provided the bulk of the code. It works almost exactly how I need it to. The code compares each row with one another and looks for matches in the individual columns. The output of the code is currently 2 numbers per match **“#,#”**. The first number is the row that the ”current” row has a match with. The second number is the number of matches that the rows share. The code does this line by line comparing with all lines. So the output can be a number of pairs. To distinguish the different matches from one another the “pairs” are separated by the space. I am attempting to include with the output values the current row that it is in. Meaning there should be three outputs if there is a match… current_row, matched_row, number_of_matched_values. In addition to including the current row, I am also needing all of the output to a list in 3 columns (Column_1=current_row, Column_2=matched_row, and Column_3= number_of_matched_values). I tried printing to the immediate window with Debug.Print R. Since I originally did not make this code, I am unsure if and where the current row is stored in the variables/arrays.
***PS:** the alpha numeric information (Letter##) is my way of putting a unique value in the cells that do not have important information in them. The data is from an index_match function from another table. 
Tmp is the amount of matches to look for in each row. **There also might not be a match in a row, that is a possible outcome.**

```
    Const TopLeftCell As String = "A8"   ' change to match where your data are

    Dim Rng As Range                        ' data range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, FirstClm As Long
    Dim Data As Variant                     ' original data (2-D)
    Dim Arr As Variant                      ' data rearranged (1-D)
    Dim Tmp As Variant                      ' working variable
    Dim R As Long, R1 As Long               ' row counters
    Dim C As Long                           ' column counter
    Dim Count() As String                   ' match counter

    With Range(TopLeftCell)
        FirstRow = .Row
        FirstClm = .Column
    End With
    C = Cells(FirstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstClm), _
'                    Cells(Rows.Count, FirstClm).End(xlUp).Offset(0, C - FirstClm))
                    '^^Don't Use!!!!!
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstClm), Cells(13, 8)) '13 is the last row in the data and 8 is the number of columns
    Data = Rng.Value

    ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(Data))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Data)
        ReDim Tmp(1 To UBound(Data, 2))
        For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Tmp(C) = Data(R, C)
        Next C
        Arr(R) = Tmp
    Next R


    ReDim Count(1 To UBound(Arr))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr) - 1
        For R1 = R + 1 To UBound(Arr)
            Tmp = 0
            For C = 1 To UBound(Arr(R))
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(Arr(R)(C), Arr(R1), 0)) Then
                    Tmp = Tmp + 1
                End If
            Next C
            If Tmp >= 1 Then                     ' change to suit

                Tmp = Format(Tmp, ",0") & ", "
                Count(R) = Count(R) & CStr(R1 + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
                Count(R1) = Count(R1) & CStr(R + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
            End If
        Next R1
    Next R

    For R = 1 To UBound(Count)
        If Len(Count(R)) Then Count(R) = Left(Count(R), Len(Count(R)) - 2)
    Next R
    ' set the output column here (2 columns right of the last data column)
    '   to avoid including this column in the evaluation
    '   it must be blank before a re-run
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(0, UBound(Data, 2) + 1)
    Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(Count)



End Sub
```

[image]